# Store data from php json into javascript dataset

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php codes that fetch the data from ms access and store it to $jsonStr somthing like:

```
$pivot_dataset = array();
   while(odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {
   // Push this data onto the end of the array
$pivot_dataset[] = array(
    'id' => odbc_result($rs,"id"),
    'year' => odbc_result($rs,"year"),
    'month' => odbc_result($rs,"month"),
    'empName' => odbc_result($rs,"empName"),
    'empPose' => odbc_result($rs,"empPos"),
    'numMc' => odbc_result($rs,"numMc"),
    'numLeave' => odbc_result($rs,"numLeave")
);
}

 odbc_close($conn);
 $jsonStr = json_encode($pivot_dataset); //[{"id": 1, "year": 2014 , "month": "JAN" ... }, { ... }];
```

But now i want to store the $jsonStr in javascript dataset. SO i do something like this:

```
var pivot_dataset = <?php 
$conn = odbc_connect('pivot_test','','') or die ("Error in connection");
$sql = "select * from empDetails"; 
$rs = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
if (!$rs)
{
  exit ("Error in Sql");
}
$pivot_dataset = array();
while(odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {
// Push this data onto the end of the array
$pivot_dataset[] = array(
    'id' => odbc_result($rs,"id"),
    'year' => odbc_result($rs,"year"),
    'month' => odbc_result($rs,"month"),
    'empName' => odbc_result($rs,"empName"),
    'empPose' => odbc_result($rs,"empPos"),
    'numMc' => odbc_result($rs,"numMc"),
    'numLeave' => odbc_result($rs,"numLeave")
);
}
odbc_close($conn);
$jsonStr = json_encode($pivot_dataset);
echo $jsonStr;
?>;
```

But its not working,i want the javascript store the data set something like this:

```
var pivot_dataset = [{"id": 1, "year": 2014 , "month": "JAN", "empName": "David", "empPos": "engineer","numMc": 1, "numLeave": 2},];
```

Someone can please correct? I'm new to this. TQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just do like

```
var pivot_dataset = <?php echo $jsonStr;  ?>
```

not like you have done the whole logic:

```
var pivot_dataset = <?php 
$conn = odbc_connect('pivot_test','','') or die ("Error in connection");
$sql = "select * from empDetails"; 
$rs = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
if (!$rs)
...........
```

First do the PHP Logic then store the data into a variable that you have done in `$jsonStr;` then next step is

```
<?php 
 $conn = odbc_connect('pivot_test','','') or die ("Error in connection");
 $sql = "select * from empDetails"; 
 $rs = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
 if (!$rs)
    {
      exit ("Error in Sql");
    }
 $pivot_dataset = array();
 while(odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {
    // Push this data onto the end of the array
   $pivot_dataset[] = array(
    'id' => odbc_result($rs,"id"),
    'year' => odbc_result($rs,"year"),
    'month' => odbc_result($rs,"month"),
    'empName' => odbc_result($rs,"empName"),
    'empPose' => odbc_result($rs,"empPos"),
    'numMc' => odbc_result($rs,"numMc"),
    'numLeave' => odbc_result($rs,"numLeave")
  );
 }
 odbc_close($conn);
$jsonStr = json_encode($pivot_dataset);
?>

<script>
var pivot_dataset = <?php echo $jsonStr;  ?>
</script>
```

that it.

Comment: thanks,.i need to try this,.but what format should i save this file?is it .php or .js?

Comment: @Ren this is in .php file, you can insert html,js,css in .php file.

Comment: its work with some modification. i just add ; at the end of var pivot_dataset and nahhh!tq